# Vue v-model with select input

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, drop-down-menu, v-model

I'm trying to have any option within my select input to be set as a value in an object. I'm trying to use v-model for this purpose but I'm not exactly sure how. Below is what I've tried to do so far.

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <select required name="category" id="category" @change="(e) => $emit('input', e.target.value)">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Category*</option>
      <option value="attendee">Attendee</option>
      <option value="distributor">Distributor</option>
      <option value="sponsor">Sponsor</option>
      <option value="media/analyst">Media/Analyst</option>
      <option value="university">University</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Need a prop to bind the selected value and pass that prop to `v-model`. E.g.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <pre>category = {{ category }}</pre>
    <select required name="category" id="category" v-model="category">
      <option value="">Category*</option>
      <option value="attendee">Attendee</option>
      <option value="distributor">Distributor</option>
      <option value="sponsor">Sponsor</option>
      <option value="media/analyst">Media/Analyst</option>
      <option value="university">University</option>
      <option value="nxp">NXP</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      category: null
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Edit: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MoKwzDbUREPNvNKw?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview)

Comment: Yes but category in the data method stays as null. It does not change to be whatever the option value is currently on. Also, v-model makes the first option not appear within the selectbox by default

Comment: @albert_anthony6 What do you mean? it's working as is in the plunker

Comment: Oh yes, you were right. It was just a typo on my end. Still facing the issue that v-model causes the select box to appear empty by default until the user interacts with it. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @albert_anthony6 initialize category to an empty string `category: ""`, I've updated the plunker

Answer (score 3):

You should add `value` prop to your component :

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <select required name="category" id="category" @change="(e) => $emit('input', e.target.value)">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Category*</option>
      <option value="attendee">Attendee</option>
      <option value="distributor">Distributor</option>
      <option value="sponsor">Sponsor</option>
      <option value="media/analyst">Media/Analyst</option>
      <option value="university">University</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
 </div>
```

```
<script>

export default {
 props:value
};
</script>
```

and use it in parent component like :

```
<my-select v-model="category"/>
...
<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      category: ''
    };
  }
};
</script>
```